# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: provider when using a ServiceBus Trigger in Azure

Tags: azure

When using a Service Bus Trigger in an Azure Function, an extension Bundle is required which is set in the file `host.json`

```
"extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 3.0.0)"
}
```

Then a message appears :

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: provider

Comment: I`m facing this same issue...

Comment: It seems related to this issue : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/30469#issuecomment-509828235

Answer (score 1):

Removing Entity Path from Azure Service Bus Connection String did the trick for me.

It's placed at the end of the Connection String:

```
Endpoint=sb://%YourNamespace%.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=%SASpolicy_name%;SharedAccessKey=%SASkey%=;EntityPath=queue-name
```

Comment: I don't have 'EntityPath' at the end of 'Endpoint' and I still have this error

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have permission to that Subscription OR resource group you will see this error. Also make sure that HOST.JSON file is in sync with - Function app Environment configurations.